Is Plato's Political Philosophy of the Best Regime in The Laws or The Republic?
Cornel West argues in his Gifford Lectures (2024) the following:
Plato's Laws is in many ways superior to The Republic. Yet it is often told that The Laws represents the "second" best or practical (non-idealist) version of Plato's political philosophy. Not only does this place a heavy emphasis on keeping theory and practice separated and balkanized, but it misses the important revision that Plato makes in his politics up to his last dialogue. By the time that The Laws is written there is no need for Philosopher-Kings, or W.E.B. Du Bois's Talented Tenth as elitist, heroic leaders who will lead us out of the cave. Rather, the key to the best regime becomes a celebration of culture through "serious play" as captured in 803d-804b when the Athenian Stranger says:

What then is the right way? We should live out our lives playing [803e] at certain pastimes—sacrificing, singing and dancing—so as to be able to win Heaven's favor and to repel our foes and vanquish them in fight. By means of what kinds of song and dance both these aims may be effected,—this has been, in part, stated in outline, and the paths of procedure have been marked out, in the belief that the poet is right when he says—[804a] “Telemachus, thine own wit will in part
Instruct thee, and the rest will Heaven supply;
For to the will of Heaven thou owest birth
And all thy nurture, I would fain believe.
”Hom. Od. 3.26 It behoves our nurslings also to be of this same mind, and to believe that what we have said is sufficient, and that the heavenly powers will suggest to them all else that concerns sacrifice and the dance,— [804b] in honor of what gods and at what seasons respectively they are to play and win their favor, and thus mold their lives according to the shape of their nature, inasmuch as they are puppets for the most part, yet share occasionally in truth.

Can we conclude that the best regime in Plato's political philosophy is this theatrical, dramatic one? Isn't the best regime the one that puts a high-priority on the importance of entertainment as a means for educating, competing, nourishing, and celebrating all that cultures have to offer, in relation to that measure of justice that extends from the gods?
